# Qt & ARM Linux cross-compilation

Tags: linux, qt, arm, cross-compiling, toolchain

Usually, I generate a Linux distribution with Yocto, to have a rootfs and a sysroot (SDK), without issue to cross-compile a Qt application for ARM targets. With the [NanoPi M2A board](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_M2), there is no yocto layer, friendlyARM provides directly an image of the SD card and a toolchain.

**1.** I did some interesting tests :

- I built a Qt helloworld on target with success => SD ok
- I built a helloworld (without Qt dependencies) on PC with the toolchain => toolchain ok

**2.** After these tests, to cross-compile my Qt application for ARM, I had this idea: I use the toolchain to cross-compile application with a copy of the rootfs (SD card) to link dependencies (as a sysroot).

I made a script (to have clear view on my environment before to use QtCreator environment):

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=/opt/sysroots/friendlyARM/toolchain/4.9.3/bin:$PATH

QT_INCLUDES="-I/tmp/1/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5            \
             -I/tmp/1/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtWidgets  \
             -I/tmp/1/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui      \
             -I/tmp/1/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtCore"


LIBS_PATH="-L/tmp/1/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"

arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -fPIE $QT_INCLUDES -o main.o main.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -fPIE $QT_INCLUDES -o mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp
/opt/qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin/moc $QT_INCLUDES mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -fPIE $QT_INCLUDES -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp

arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --sysroot=/tmp/1/ -o hello main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o $LIBS_PATH -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
```

Note: `/tmp/1` is the path of the rootfs (copy of SD).

Output

```
> /opt/sysroots/friendlyARM/toolchain/4.9.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.3/../../../../arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd:
> cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
> /opt/sysroots/friendlyARM/toolchain/4.9.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.3/../../../../arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd:
> cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory collect2: error: ld
> returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand why I haven't problem with a simple helloworld (without Qt dependencies) but I have link issue with crt1, crti just when I add Qt libraries.

I tried lot of things, without success.

Comment: It's armv7. Usual Debian and its cross-compiler should work for this board.

Comment: I think you have to use QT SDk to compile the application and you need to use macros only like ${CC}, $CXX} etc